# How do you find the HyperLinkField in code behind?

Tags: c#, gridview

I have a requirement to append data to the DataNavigateUrlFormatString property of the HyperLinkField of a GridView control.

My problem is I can't seem to find any way to acquire a handle to the control in the RowDataBound event of the Grid. Unlike other controls in the Grid, it doesn't seem to be accessible in the same way b/c it doesn't have a ControlID to find it. So where this will work with other controls

```
CheckBox status = (CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("chkStatus");
if (status != null)
{
   // do something here
}
```

The same won't for the Hyperlinkfield because I can't use the FindControl method.

I know there has to be some way to access it b/c inspecting the e.Row object I can clearly see it and the DataNavigateUrlFormatString property I'd like to modify. I just haven't been able to find a way to acquire a handle to it.

Every post I've found makes reference to the HyperLink control, not the HyperLinkField. I prefer not changing the existing Grid structure of this item to a HyperLink if I can avoid it.

How can you access the HyperLinkField in the RowDataBoundevent? Is it possible?

Comment: Assuming that the data for the control is coming from your data model, then you defintely hold **nit** be trying to modify the control. You should modify the data, and let the UI update itself. That's a basic idea in keeping the model and business logic separate from the UI. That way if your UI changes, you don't need to change the business logic or data model.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I do understand what you're saying but this is a request from the business to accommodate dynamic values appended to the URI so making it a part of the Model isn't really an option here. It's not elegant I agree, but what I'm asking isn't really much different from dynamically setting values in the URI using a Hyperlink which folks do all the time. I think I've found a solution that I'll post once tested.

Comment: Well, I don't know your business model, so can't say for sure, but I would have thought that dynamic values in the URI is data, and therefore should be set in the model. Data should be completely independent of the UI, which was my point. Anyway, as long as you've found something that works for you, that's fine.